# Convert a collection of references into a reference to a collection of owned values

Tags: collections, rust, reference

Is there any way to convert a collection of references into a reference to a collection of owned values in Rust? My particular use case is converting a `BTreeSet<&T>` into a `&BTreeSet<T>`. I have a `match` where one arm returns a singleton `BTreeSet` created from a reference to a value but the other returns a reference to an existing `BTreeSet`. I'm not sure if this is possible without a `clone()`, but figured I would ask.

Comment: It seems to by an XY problem, so you better provide the higher level problem that you're trying to solve. For the current question - you can only own objects from a reference after you `clone()` it. How would you imagine Rust to simply give you ownership of the object when you have just a permission to *look* at the object?

Comment: It's possible to work with owned-or-borrowed data in some situations using the tools in [`std::borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/index.html), but it'd be easier to suggest a suitable solution if we could see the code structure you're trying to fit this into.